# Table has no column named [variable]?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have set up a new table in my database. I have other existing tables that work fine, but this newest one came later and is proving problematic.

The table in question is the bar table. I have checked the structure of the database from SQLite Database Browser and I see the column I expected. There appears to be 3 possibilities.

1) The database was not created properly - but I can see the column so I think this is unlikely?

2) There is a problem with my input method - I have similar methods implemented for other tables.

3) There is a problem with upgrading my database version

I have truncated much of the code to isolate only the important parts.

```
public class DBmanager {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBmanagerdb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Shared strings and main table
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "drinkTable";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "drink_name";
public static final String KEY_BAR = "bar_name";
public static final String KEY_SCORE = "drink_score";
public static final String KEY_VOL = "volume";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
public static final String KEY_DRINKABV = "abv";
public static final String KEY_FAVE = "favorite";
public static final String MYTAB_DRINKCOUNT = "mytab_drinkCount";

// Strings for ABV
private static final String ABV_TABLE = "abvTable";
public static final String KEY_ABV_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME_ABV = KEY_NAME;
public static final String KEY_ABV = "abv_value";

//
private static final String VERSION_TABLE = "versionTable";
public static final String VERSION_NUMBER = "version";

private static final String BAR_TABLE = "barTable";
private static final String KEY_LAT = "barLatitude";
private static final String KEY_LONG = "barLongitude";
public static final String KEY_BARID = "barId";

// Strings for My Tab

;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_BAR
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_PRICE + " DOUBLE, " + KEY_VOL + " DOUBLE, "
                + KEY_DRINKABV + " DOUBLE, " + KEY_SCORE + " DOUBLE,"
                + MYTAB_DRINKCOUNT + " INTEGER," + KEY_FAVE + " INTEGER);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ABV_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ABV_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME_ABV
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ABV + " DOUBLE);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + VERSION_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + VERSION_NUMBER
                + " INTEGER);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + BAR_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_BAR
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LAT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LONG
                + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        newVersion = oldVersion;
        Log.i("Values", "OldVersion: " + oldVersion + "     New Version: "
                + newVersion);

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BAR_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public long enterNewBar(String barName) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_BAR, barName);
    cv.put(KEY_LAT, "hello");
    cv.put(KEY_LONG, "world");
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public boolean checkUniqueBar(String barName) {

    boolean flag = false;

    String myQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_BAR + " FROM "
            + DATABASE_TABLE;

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BAR)) == barName) {
                flag = true;

            }
        }
        c.close();

    }
    return flag;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
  05-22 00:53:56.859: E/SQLiteLog(8496): (1) table drinkTable has no column named barLongitude
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496): Error inserting barLongitude=world barLatitude=hello bar_name=TEst
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table drinkTable has no column named barLongitude (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO drinkTable(barLongitude,barLatitude,bar_name) VALUES (?,?,?)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.DBmanager.enterNewBar(DBmanager.java:555)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.fragments.MainFrag.calculateScore(MainFrag.java:288)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at mjd.mdflip.areyoudrunk.fragments.MainFrag.onClick(MainFrag.java:145)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    05-22 00:53:56.909: E/SQLiteDatabase(8496):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the error? Do you have the full stacktrace?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BAR)) == barName` won't work. You should use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Try creating all the tables at one time, along with their columns. That might help.

Comment: Justin,I threw the full stacktrace in the question...I will try to format it. Matiash, thanks for the heads up. Currently testing in a case where it won't return a value so wouldn't have seen if it worked or not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting into `drinkTable`, not `barTable`:

Change

```
return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

to

```
return ourDatabase.insert(BAR_TABLE, null, cv);
```

A better way to write your method would be:

```
public boolean checkUniqueBar(String barName) {

    boolean flag = false;

    String myQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) " FROM " 
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_BAR + "=?";

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(myQuery, new String[] { barName } );
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        if( c.getInteger(0) > 0 )
            flag = true;

        c.close();

    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess staring at the problem for so long made me gloss over the fact I could have been using the wrong table.

I also changed my method to what you have. As I said earlier that method was thrown together quickly, but yours definitely seems nicer.

Comment: Sure thing. I've looked at your code twice, but it took the logcat to see it. As for improving the `checkUniqueBar()` method, I like to reduce the amount of data exchanged as much as possible. Rather than walking the table yourself, you make SQLite do the work and just check the results.